# d3.geoBounds() failes to obtain correct latitude/longitude values. Wrong usage or bug?

Tags: d3.js

I am working with d3-geo trying to draw a map of Bonn/Germany. After I failed to correctly scale the map I found that either my data is somehow malformed, a necessary data-sanitization step is not available or d3-geo maybe has a bug.

The minimal example can be found here: https://bl.ocks.org/BastiTee/23e05990a761b4d616ae42d0ed036307

As you can see, I only load the data from `bonn.json` and print the result of d3.geoBounds. The values (-180,-90 | 180,90) are incorrect.

Using both http://mapshaper.org/ and http://geojsonlint.com/ I am able to load the data without any error, displaying the map correctly. If I put in other map data into my code I see realistic lat/long values. I manually checked and there is nothing outside the 50.* or 7.* range.
Even in the [gist itself](https://gist.github.com/BastiTee/23e05990a761b4d616ae42d0ed036307#file-bonn-json), the data is mapped correctly.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong, is it bad data or is this a bug in d3-geo?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I hardcode the expected value `var bounds = [[7.0226282622, 50.6327277725], [7.2106608053, 50.7743702078]]` the remaining code works like expected. It boils down to this particular call.

Comment: I crossposted as d3-geo bug at https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/issues/118

Comment: Solved. https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/issues/118 The coordinates need to be reversed.